# Duplicate columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, nan

I'm looking for a way to duplicate columns of the table. This is my code

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np


env_height = 9
env_width = 9
pixels = 40

action_1 = ['up', 'down', 'left', 'right']
action_2 = action_1.copy
actions = [action_1] + [action_2]
state_space = []

for x in range (0, (env_width * pixels), pixels):
    for y in range (0, (env_height * pixels) , pixels):
        state_space += [[x,y]] 

state = [str(s) for s in state_space]
q_table = pd.DataFrame(columns = actions, index=state)


print (q_table)
```

I want the output to be something like this

```
            up   down left right up  down left right     
[0, 0]      NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  Nan  NaN  NaN  NaN
[0, 40]     NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
[0, 80]     NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
[0, 120]    NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
[0, 160]    NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
.......
```

Comment: The big problem here is that `action_2 = action_1.copy` doesn't call the `copy` method. You need `action_2 = action_1.copy()`, with the `()` to make it actually run. FWIW I find the traceback utterly confusing on this, if you were to make that mistake in a large code base. It doesn't quite do what you want, but you'll at least be able to see the output

Answer (score 0):

Try to add space (i. e.`"up "`) to the words in `action_2` because in your way you are just overwriting columns from `action_1`.

```py
action_2 = [word + " " for word in action_1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `copy()` instead of `copy`. Alternatively you can simply assign `action_2 = action_1`. This wont replace the original list.

Then flatten the list of lists `actions`

```py
env_height = 9
env_width = 9
pixels = 40

action_1 = ['up', 'down', 'left', 'right']
action_2 = action_1
actions = [action_1] + [action_2]
state_space = []

for x in range (0, (env_width * pixels), pixels):
    for y in range (0, (env_height * pixels) , pixels):
        state_space += [[x,y]] 

# flatten the list of lists
actions = [item for sublist in actions for item in sublist]
q_table = pd.DataFrame(columns = actions, index=state)

print(q_table)

      up down left right up down left right
[0, 0]  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
[0, 40] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```